# Is it legit to store CQL tuples with null components in Cassandra 3.x

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

I have to store a protocol buffer structure in Cassandra 3.x. It is defined in a .proto file as:

```
message Attribute
{
    required string key = 1;
    oneof value {
        int64 integerValue = 2;
        float floatValue = 3;
        string stringValue = 4;
    }
}
```

To store multiple `Attributes` I was thinking about this CQL definition.

```
CREATE TABLE ... attributes: map<text, tuple<int, float, text> ...
```

and in each tuple 2 of 3 components would actually be `null`. I haven't tested this syntax yet but are there any downsides using this approach? Maybe there is a better way, i.e. User Defined Types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this out.  I'll start with a simple table, containing a `valuemap` column of type `map<text,tuple<int,float,text>` as you have above:

```
CREATE TABLE tupleTest (
  key text,
  value text, 
  valuemap map<text, FROZEN<tuple<int,float,text>>>,
  PRIMARY KEY (key));
```

I'll `INSERT` some data:

```
INSERT INTO tupletest (key,value,valuemap) VALUES ('1','A',{'a':(0,0.0,'hi')});
INSERT INTO tupletest (key,value,valuemap) VALUES ('2','B',{'b':(0,null,'hi')});
INSERT INTO tupletest (key,value,valuemap) VALUES ('3','C',{'c':(null,null,'hi')});
```

And then I'll `SELECT` it, just to see:

```
aploetz@cqlsh:stackoverflow> SELECT * FROM tupletest ;

 key | value | valuemap
-----+-------+---------------------------
   3 |     C | {'c': (None, None, 'hi')}
   2 |     B |    {'b': (0, None, 'hi')}
   1 |     A |       {'a': (0, 0, 'hi')}

(3 rows)
```

The main apprehension about explicitly `INSERT`ing NULL values into Cassandra, is that in "normal" columns they actually create tombstones.  But since we are not setting an entire column to NULL, merely an element in a tuple (nested inside a map), this is not the case.  In fact, they are showing as `None`.  And when I view the underlying SSTables, I also do not see evidence that a tombstone has been written.

Normally, I'd say that explicitly `INSERT`ing a NULL into Cassandra is a terrible, terrible idea.  But in this case, it shouldn't cause you any issues.  Now, as to whether or not this is considered to be "legit" or a good practice...well, my data modeling senses do not approve.  I would find another way to represent the absence of a value in a tuple type, as someone (the developer who follows you) could see this and interpret that as being "ok" to explicitly `INSERT` NULLs into other column values.

Comment: Great answer Aaron, thanks. I have never seen the `valuemap` type before and it's also not documented on the CQL 3.3 data types page. Do you know where I can find some details about this type?

Comment: @reikje `valuemap` isn't a type it's a column name of a map that contains a tuple nested inside it.  Sorry for the confusion there.

Comment: I see, got a bit confused because of the map-suffix :)